# Android share display on another devices

Tags: android, screen, screenshot

i'm working on share the tablet display with more than one table (all rooted) connected through WiFi , i'm using the following approach (all inside one thread) :

1- i take a screen shot.

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);    
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -P " + "/sdcard/test/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();          
os.close();
sh.waitFor();
```

2- compress the screen shot image.

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test/img.png");
OutputStream outputStream = null;
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test/img2.png");
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 15, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

3- open socket and send the compressed image to another tablet.

this is working but my problem is the viewing delay in the other tablet it took 4-5 sec to refresh the new display , is there any better approach to have it real time display?

Comment: I guess you're asking a bit much, you're limited to your Wi-Fi, reading an image from your SD, compressing it and sending it. On the other side is also doing a lot of process, I imagine, that even if you optmize that, it will not grant you more than one sec

Comment: @Rigotti Ok ... is there any other way to reach what i need?

Answer (score 3):

Unfotrtunately, this function will take long time. It is linked with process lifecycle, IPC and the slow file system. You need to have a look at [this library](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) or the [source code of /system/bin/screenshot util.](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/search?q=screenshot&ref=cmdform) You have to reuse native(c-language) functions from sources, and it is not a trivial task.