# Android Screen shot image size

Tags: android, screenshot

I use the below code to get a screen shot :

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/img.png", null,null);
sh.waitFor();
```

the captured screen image size about 1.4 MB (1024 * 768 pixel) .

1- Is there any way to have the size smaller without compressing the image ?

2- Is there another Shell command to execute to have less image size?

EDIT : i changed the image format to `img.gif` but the size still the same.

Comment: to use the above i guess you should root your device. you will have to ask users to root their device to use your app

Comment: @Raghunandan you are right , the device is rooted and the above code is working 100% but my issue in the image size i want it smaller.

Comment: It is normal size. Why do you need to decrease it? Why don't you compress it to gzip for example?

Comment: You can check out this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @matreshkin im sending the image through socket to another tablet i want to decrease the image size to reduce the transfer time , compressing the image increase the delay time.

Comment: 2 bytes per pixel - I think it is impossible to decrease the size without compressing, in general. Try low-level compressing, find the balance between the speed and the size of processing image.

Comment: If yiu want to transfer video, try send only changed areas of whole the screen

Comment: @matreshkin can you guide me how to do it , my question related to a previous question i asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948607/android-share-display-on-another-devices . thanks for your concern.